# What is sourceannotations.h?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Visual studio keeps including sourceannotations.h to my C++ projects. This file seems to be .NET, and I am not using CLR (only native C++).

I wanted to take preprocessed .cpp file to check it in external tool (like clang or cppcheck) but they don't support MS syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), source annotations are used to reduce code defects and it does not seem specific to .Net.